# Continuing table on multiple pages with tabularx

Tags: tables, captions, longtable, tabularx

**Problem:**

Continuing table on multiple pages using the tabularx package.

**Questions:**

1. What is the appropriate way to include "continued ..." caption at the end and beginning of the table when crossing a page?
2. What is the best way to get the headers to follow on a new page for a long table?

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,tabularx,caption}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{y}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\captionsetup{justification=justified,singlelinecheck=off}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htp]
  \centering
  \footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
  \setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\bfseries}l@{\hspace{6pt}}y{50pt}|*{4}{Y|}y{10pt}|*{4}{Y|}Y}
    \hline
    Solution & \multicolumn{11}{c}{\bfseries Criteria} \\
    \cline{2-12}
    & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I & J & K \\
    \hline
     Agora Voting & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
    \\
     Text 2 &&&&&&&&&&
    \\
     Text 3 &&&&&&&&&&
    \\
     Text 4 &&&&&&&&&&
    \\
     Text 5 &&&&&&&&&&
    \\
     Text 6 &&&&&&&&&&
    \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{3}X}
    A: Caption 1\newline B: Caption 2\newline C: Caption 3\newline D: Caption 4 & E: Caption 5\newline F: Caption 6\newline G: Caption 7\newline H: Caption 8 & I: Caption 9\newline J: Caption 10\newline K: Caption 11\\
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{Text text text}\label{tab:comparison}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Desireable outcome:**

[image]
[image]

Comment: there's no point in using `tabularx` with a preamble of `XXX` as you know in advance the column widths, why not simply use `longtable` to get a multi-page table?

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle, I have adopted your suggestion and posted a new question regarding small issues on longtable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP states this question has no more meaning in comments