# Table wanted that breaks across pages and has the wanted horizontal size

Tags: header-footer, longtable, tabularx

Working quite a time now with tables I get the impression that sizes are not respected.

I usually do:

```
  \begin{longtable}[H]{|m{0.3\linewidth}|m{0.7\linewidth}|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Header1} & \textbf{Header2}\\\hline
    \endfirsthead
    \hline
    \textbf{Header1} & \textbf{Header2}\\\hline
    \endhead
    Content\\\hline
    \caption{Caption}
  \end{longtable}
```

The horizontal size is bigger than expected. I compare the endpoint of the line above the footer with the right margin of the table. Those 2 shall get the same x-value, which is not the case yet.

When I use tabularx the x-value is the same:

```
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|lX|}
    \hline
    Content & Content \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
```

But since I have tables that are longer than one page I need a new solution since tabularx just keeps continuing the table into the footer and does not break on a new page. As suggested here, I changed to longtable: [Continuing table on multiple pages with tabularx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237254/continuing-table-on-multiple-pages-with-tabularx)

longtable properly breaks across pages (even repeating the header) but does not respect the size, tabularx respects the size but does not break across pages. Is there a working solution to this issue?

EDIT: For all those searching the answer here is the working code I use now (2 columns example):

```
\begin{longtable}{|m{0.25\dimexpr\linewidth-4\tabcolsep-3\arrayrulewidth}|m{0.75\dimexpr\linewidth-4\tabcolsep-3\arrayrulewidth}|}
    \hline
    \textbf{1} & \textbf{2}\\\hline
    \endfirsthead
    \hline
    \textbf{1} & \textbf{2}\\\hline
    \endhead
    1 & 2\\\hline
    \caption{1}
  \end{longtable}
```

Comment: `[H]`? Get rid of that.

Comment: Load package `showframe` to better judge. At the left and right of every cell content, a bit of space is added. Try `@{}` between the different columns (column definition).

Comment: longtable has no `H` option any the table is specified too wide `{|m{0.3\linewidth}|m{0.7\linewidth}|}` has a total width of `\linewidth+4\tabcolsep+3\arrayrulewidth`

Comment: longtable respects the size that you specified, you just specified the wrong size:-)

Answer (score 5):

You have to leave space for the column padding and rules so

```
\newlength\mylength
\setlength\mylength{\dimexpr\linewidth-4\tabcolsep-3\arrayrulewidth}
 % in general you need to remove
 % 2\tabcolsep for each column and 1\arrayrulewidth for each |

....

\begin{longtable}{|m{0.3\mywidth}|m{0.7\mywidth}|}
```

Comment: So would this guys be of use? `\newlength\mylengthForOneColumn
\setlength\mylengthForOneColumn{\dimexpr\linewidth-3\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}
\newlength\mylengthForTwoColumns
\setlength\mylengthForTwoColumns{\dimexpr\linewidth-4\tabcolsep-3\arrayrulewidth}
\newlength\mylengthForThreeColumns
\setlength\mylengthForThreeColumns{\dimexpr\linewidth-5\tabcolsep-4\arrayrulewidth}
\newlength\mylengthForFourColumns
\setlength\mylengthForFourColumns{\dimexpr\linewidth-6\tabcolsep-5\arrayrulewidth}`

Comment: @gentlesea In general, vertical rules should be avoided. They are often just distracting.

Comment: @gentlesea There are packages like `supertabular` and `ltxtable` and others that probaly can do a better job. David Carlisle will know more.

Comment: @gentlesea no point in defining them all in advance. (and for one column you want to subtract  2\tabcolsep not 3) just allocate \mylength once in the preamble and then set it just before the  table in each case adjusting for whatever columns and rules (or `@`-expressions that you have that take up width.

Comment: @gentlesea: If you want to predefine some common tabular preamble setups, use `\newcolumntype`. E.g. `\newcolumntype\tabtwocol{p{2cm}p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2cm-4\tabcolsep}}`

Comment: Can anyone provide me a working example for 4 columns please? In my case it always gets too wide...

Comment: @gentlesea for example `\begin{longtable}{|m{0.2\mywidth}|m{0.2\mywidth}|m{0.2\mywidth}|m{0.2\mywidth}|m{0.4\mywidth}|`  where because there are 4 columns and 5 rules you want `\setlength\mylength{\dimexpr\linewidth-8\tabcols‌ep-5\arrayrulewidth} `

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/view/leq5913zlssb0pk/Longtable.png

Comment: @gentlesea your question (any question) would be much easier to understand if it had an example that could be used. Examples should start `\documentclass` and end `\end{document}` really isn't possible to debug an image.

Comment: You are of course right. But I my minimal working example does not compile for a reason I do not see. I fixed it anyway in my big document.

Comment: `\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, openright, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
  \begin{longtable}{|m{0.5\dimexpr\linewidth-5\tabcolsep-4\arrayrulewidth}|m{0.5\dimexpr\linewidth-5\tabcolsep-4\arrayrulewidth}|}
    \hline
    1 & 2\\\hline
  \end{longtable}
  \begin{longtable}{|m{0.25\dimexpr\linewidth-9\tabcolsep-8\arrayrulewidth}|m{0.25\dimexpr\linewidth-9\tabcolsep-8\arrayrulewidth}|m{0.25\dimexpr\linewidth-9\tabcolsep-8\arrayrulewidth}|m{0.25\dimexpr\linewidth-9\tabcolsep-8\arrayrulewidth}|}
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\\hline
  \end{longtable}
\end{document}`

Comment: @gentlesea best to put code in your question not comments but why do you have `5\tabcolsep` in a 2 column table as stated above several times each column has 2\tabcolsep padding so you need to subtract 4\tabcolsep for that case, and you have 3 rules so you need to subtract 3\arrayrulewidth not 4\arrayrulewidth, your 4 column table is similarly wrong. if you have 4 columns each with tabcolsep either side, you need to subtract 8\tabcolsep and you have 5 rules so you need to subtract 5\arrayrulewidth